# How to use ID or CLASS instead of using name in Bootstrap Validator for form revalidation

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

```
$('#freeTicketGenerationFroms').formValidation('revalidateField', 'first_name[]');
```

to

```
$('#freeTicketGenerationFroms').formValidation('revalidateField', "#first_name"+id);
```

How to use ID or CLASS instead of using name in Bootstrap Validator for form revalidation